# Keep textures from stretching when extruding faces in Blender?

Tags: blender, modeling, game-development, texture-mapping

I'm trying to make a map in Blender but I'm getting weird texture stretching problem when I extrude along some faces. I've enabled "Correct Face Attributes" in Options, and it helps, but in some cases I still get this stretching:

[image]

Any pointers on how I could fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I have removed the `unity3d` tag as your question isn't _directly_ related to Unity even if you may be using the model later in Unity.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Found the perfect answer here: https://blenderartists.org/t/extruded-correct-face-attributes-texture-is-distorted/1270185

Using hex-planar UV mapping, things are looking as they should!
[Fixed Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feCKO.png)